# Eleven 把-related sentences containing grammar errors (e.g. 我把作业已经交给老师了): how do we explain these errors?

Tags: grammar, particles

[This post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/gijs7r/can_anyone_help_me_do_this_task_theres_one/) gives eleven 把 sentences **containing grammar errors** ([original image](https://i.redd.it/vcntj09x9ey41.jpg)).  It looks like a worthwhile exercise.  (A native Chinese speaker /u/Lvguichen gave corrections without explanations.)

I'm hoping to get feedback on my understanding, so **please critique my explanations below**.

In the following sentences the highlighted terms are misplaced:

> (1) 我把作业**已经**交给老师了。 -->   我**已经**把作业交给老师了。
>   (4) 他把英语课本**没有**放回书架上。  -->  他**没有**把英语课本放回书架上。
>   (5) 地上有水，你把背包**不要**放在地上。  -->  地上有水，你**不要**把背包放在地上。

In the following sentences the highlighted verbs lack [complements](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22ba%22_sentences#.E6.8A.8A_Sentences_with_Complements):

> (3) 我们先把啤酒**喝**再走，好吗？  -->   我们先把啤酒**喝完**再走，好吗？
>   (7) 别忘了把身份证**带**！  -->   别忘了把身份证**带上**！

These two are incorrect because they involve transitive verbs which lack objects:

> (2) 他不喜欢把自己的东西**借**。  -->   他不喜欢把自己的东西**借出去**。
>   (10) 你不可能**把他认识**，你们从来没见过面。  -->  你不可能**认识他**，你们从来没见过面。

(I can't think of a reasonable way to say 认识他 beginning 把他...)

This one reads like something clumsily translated from English (and ignores Chinese grammar):

> (6) 弟弟常常藏脏衣服在床底下。  --> 弟弟常常**把**脏衣服**藏**在床底下。

The following seems wrong because 把 requires a positive action (把论文**写完** is okay, but 把论文**写不完** is not):

> (9) 来不及了，我**把**论文**写不完**！ --> 我**不能把**论文**写完**！

Below 当 and 作 seem completely wrong:

> (11) 别**当**我**作**傻子了。 --> 别**把**我**当**傻子了

---

For this one, I don't understand the grammar error (/u/Lvguichen
 simply deleted the 了):

> (8) 顾客**把**一些水果**放在**购物篮里**了**。

Similar examples are online: 女孩**把**钱**放在**包里**了**<sup>[[src]](https://www.jiuwen.cn/ask/550811.aspx)</sup> and 昨天**把**东西**放在**桌子上**了**<sup>[[src]](https://www.120ask.com/question/80150806.htm)</sup>.  In fact, even the [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22ba%22_sentences#What_is_a_.E6.8A.8A_sentence.3F) gives such an example 她**把**我的手机**放在**她的包里**了**.

Comment: For (7), your answer is correct, but a more common way to say it is 别忘了带身份证 (i.e. not using 把 at all).

Answer (score 1):

> *(11) 别当我作傻子了。 --> 别把我当傻子了*
>
> another way to fix it is use "当是" instead of "当作" e.g. 别当我是傻子了
>
> [当][我][是][傻子] is [v] + [n] + [v] + [n]
>
> [当(我)作][傻子] is [verb + (n) + verb complement] + [n] (*we don't insert noun between verb and verb complement*)

~

> *(8) 顾客把一些水果[放]在购物篮里[了] --> 顾客把一些水果[放了]在购物篮里*
>
> If 了 is treated as a verb particle that indicate the action is completed, it is more effective to place it directly after the verb 放
>
> If 了 is treated as a final particle that indicate change of situation, the sentence seems incomplete (what made the customers not put some vegetable in the basket before?)

Comment: I think 顾客把一些水果放在了购物篮里 sounds more natural for 8

Comment: No,  顾客把一些水果放了在购物篮里 is the native way to speak. ; 顾客把一些水果放在了购物篮里 is unnatural

Comment: Well I haven't really lived in China for like 7 years now... even though I am native

Answer (score 1):

“把”字句语法：

施事-把-受事-动作-补语

注意：

1、动作不能没有补语（2）（3）（7）

2、不及物动词、系动词、趋向动词、表感受的动词不能作为“把”字句的动作
（10）

3、否定词、能愿词和时间词提到“把”之前（1）（4）（5）

4、“把”字句不能应用可能补语（9）

我一天以内把工作做得完->我一天以内能把工作做完

补充：

5、“把”的宾语可以确指、泛指，但不能不定指

把一本书拿过来好吗？-> 把那本书拿过来好吗？

6、“把”字句的结果补语、状态补语指向的应是宾语而非主语

他把故事听高兴了->他听故事听高兴了

另：什么时候非用“把”字句不可（6）（11）

[Chris Xia的回答](https://www.zhihu.com/answer/35431589)

实际上这两句不能算完全错误，现在许多人也能接受（但正如你所说，不太自然）

（8）是正确的

注：

以上规则皆仅适用于纯粹的现代汉语，役于文风、对仗、修辞、音律、仿古等用者常有例外

夫妻双双把家还

却把青梅嗅

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 8th one [顾客把一些水果放在购物篮里。] I think the teorical "mistake" that they want to point out here is the use of "一些", as Chinese lengage manuals usually stress that the use of "把" is only for a "definite object" (which means specific object that both the speaker and the listener know what they are refering to), and that's why you must not use "一些", "一个", etc; intead, they say you have to us "那些" 等等。　I personally don't agry with that rule the way the state it. It may apply when you just want to produce an effect on an object, but in the cases like the given example (把.....[verb]在...; or 把...[verb]成..., etc) I think it's correct, at least I don't know any other way to say it without using把. I'm sorry for not giving a definitive answer, but I just saw nobady mentioned this and this is better than nothing. I hope someone here, maybe a native, can help a little more on this issue.